No code coverage data available. Profiler was not initialized
I wanna switch the code coverage tool from opencover to dotnet-coverage. I tried it out but I always get the message

"No code coverage data available. Profiler was not initialized."

My code is:
dotnet-coverage collect -f xml -o 'outputpath' "dotnet test 'path to solution'"

I tried looking for a solution and I read the documentation but I haven't found anything that helped. Can anyone help me please? I know there are other ways of code coverage but I would like to use dotnet-coverage

I think you got the syntax wrong.
In command line, just navigate to directory, where solution file is located (the .sln file).
Then it is enough to execute this command:
dotnet-coverage collect dotnet test -o outputfile.xml -f xml

So:

solution is detected automatically
there is no quotation around dotnet test

